# ajax rest properties not view when i change the repository in spring boot (use Data tables to view details)

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot, datatables

I added the ajax cord for retrieve my data from the server.It works fine previously. I get these data without filter fields from my query. But in this time I want to select some feilds.. not all. So I cerate a query from this.

```
@Query("select u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.nic, u.agency from User u")
List<User> findAllUsers();
```

This is my query.When I get this query from the ajax call data retrieve success.I **checked with it postman**. Query works fine. But in JSP it doesn't view... I use datatables for view data... I does't change my JSP(for previous query it works fine). when I get the jsp it shows this error message.

```
DataTables warning: table id=usrTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

I can't understand what's the error...I doesn't change ajax and only change my ajax data retreive query...

this is my jsp and ajax

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Users List</title>
        <jsp:include page="template/styles.jsp"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bootstrapCssTest" class="hidden"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row headerRow1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <jsp:include page="template/styles.jsp"/>
                    <jsp:include page="template/stylesLoadHigh.jsp"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row headerRow1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <jsp:include page="template/banner.jsp"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="authheader">
                    <%@include file="template/message.jsp" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <jsp:include page="template/header.jsp"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="well lead">List of Users</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="generic-container">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <!-- Default panel contents -->
                                <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                                    <table class="table table-hover" id="usrTable">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>ID</th>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>NIC / Emp No</th>
                                                <th>Agency</th>
                                                <th width="100"></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <%  if ((role.contains("ADMIN"))) { %>
                            <div class="well">
                                <a href="<c:url value='/newuser' />">Add New User</a>
                            </div>
                            <% }%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <jsp:include page="template/footer.jsp"/>
        </div>
        <jsp:include page="template/stylesLoadHigh.jsp"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </body>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tableProduct = $('#usrTable').DataTable({
                "bSort": true
                , "oLanguage": {"sZeroRecords": "", "sEmptyTable": ""}
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/all/users/view/sw',
                success: function (result) {
                    var jString = JSON.stringify(result);
                    var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);
                    for (var x = 0; x < jdata.length; x++) {
                        var td1 = jdata[x].id;
                        var td2 = jdata[x].firstName + " " + jdata[x].lastName;
                        var td3 = jdata[x].nic;
                        var td4 = jdata[x].agency;
                        var td5 = '<form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateUser" target="_blank"><input type="hidden" name="userId" class="btn btn-success" value="' + jdata[x].id + '"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="View"/><input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"value="${_csrf.token}"/></form>';
                        tableProduct.row.add([td1, td2, td3, td4, td5]).draw(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

this is my domain(data feilds)

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String nic;

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    private String mobile;
    private String email;
    private String status;

    private String agency;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;

    private String password;

    private String impoVat;
```

How can I retrive data to my datatables

Comment: How does `jdata` look like after you have parsed it?

Comment: @davidkonrad jdata like 1,abc company,10,Rc com  ...Its not mentiond like json header with their feilds.It retreive like normal array with comma...